# How to render Tab navigation with Drawer navigation simultaneously in react-navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I'm looking to render both the drawer navigation and tab navigation components simultaneously in my app.

I created a file named `root.js` and wrote both of components in this file:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { Login, SecondPage, ThirdPage } from './components/index';
```

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

And this is the component:

```
const MainDrawer = () => {

  return (

    <Fragment>
    <NavigationContainer >

      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Second Page" component={SecondPage} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Third Page" component={ThirdPage} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

<NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SecondPage} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Third Page" component={ThirdPage} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>


    </Fragment>

  )

export default MainDrawer;
```

But components got duplicated as you can see in following screenshot, How can i merge these two components and render them as one component?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `NavigationContainer`. Put your `Tab.Navigator` as your first screen.

```js
const LoginWithTabs = () => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SecondPage} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Third Page" component={ThirdPage} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const MainDrawer = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer >
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="LoginWithTabs" component={LoginWithTabs} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Second Page" component={SecondPage} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Third Page" component={ThirdPage} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )

export default MainDrawer;
```

Note that your Drawer will contain 3 entries, and if you select "Second Page", you will be redirected to `SecondPage` and you won't see the Tabs. If you want a more complex behaviour, you need to create a custom component to replace the default one for the Drawer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I changed my code to what you said but it didn't work , Duplication is vanished but Tab doesn't show as well, Haven't you forgotten to export first function?```LoginWithTabs```

Comment: Sorry buddy, It worked, I had forgotten to import ```LoginWithTabs``` into ```Drawer.Navigator```, You saved my time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I need Tabs in all screens, I already created a custom component for Drawer. Please take a look to this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/5LhsSzk Then imported that into default Drawer but Tab still doesn't show in all screens, I need Tab in all screens Do you have any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: I fixed it buddy, Thanks again for your help

Comment: @roz333 - How made you tabs with all screens? I want to show tabs and navigation in all screens. Can you help me please?

Comment: @RajuRajpurohit Buddy you should make a tab navigation then import it into stack navigation

Comment: @roz333 - I have created a tab navigator and drawer navigator with custom components. I want to get current active route. But due to child route, It creating an issue. Are you have any idea for get active route (currently active screen)?

Comment: Hi @roz333 How did you render tabs and drawer simultaneously, can you please share a example. I want to show tabs in all screens selected from drawer menu but unable to do it.